# QWebView::settings()->setUserStyleSheetUrl() from QtWebKit to QtWebEngine?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I'm upgrading my code from Qt 5.5 to Qt 5.6, but I didn't find a way to port the following code:

```
QWebEngineView *qwebview = new QWebEngineView(this);
qwebview->settings()->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl("qrc:/about.css"));
qwebview->setHtml(fileContentStr);
```

What is the best way to insert a user CSS using the new Qt Web Engine?

Comment: The qwebenginesetting hasn't the method setUserStyleSheetUrl...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read here : [Bug Report on QWebEngine](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51192?jql=text%20~%20%22setUserStyleSheetUrl%22), you'll see that :

> The only opportunity to inject CSS code into the WebEngineView is
>   using JavaScript. It would be nice to have an appropriate API for this
>   and it could look like our already existing UserScripts API.

It seems pretty clear : **you can't use the WebSettings anymore to insert CSS.** Instead, you will have to use HTML/JavaScript to do that.

I don't know if it will help you, but here is an extract of what I have done .

In my `.cpp` :

```
m_pView = new QWebEngineView(this);

QUrl startURL = QUrl("path/to/index.html");

m_pView->setUrl(startURL);
```

And in the `index.html` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- Many JS scripts here -->

        <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" >
      <div ui-view class="page"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Alexis P, my style.css is in a qrc file... But, I'll try your solution.

Thanks!